# Font Awesome icon is disappearing when i click on it?

Tags: html, css, icons

this is somthing weird i think.

When i click on an icon it disappears, and if i reload the page it comes back again.

I am using this html code in a navbar

```
<li class="hover-item" style="font-size:14px;padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;text-align:left;">
  <span>
    <a style="color:#B3BAC1;" href="./?page=logs" target="frame">
      <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Logs
    </a>
  </span>
</li>
```

What could cause this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Your page is redirected to `./?page=logs`?

Comment: Yes in an iframe

Comment: So if the page is changed there won't be any of the previous contents there right? Or post the full code if something is missing here

Comment: i have a fixed navbar an a fixed footer, in the middle an iframe. so the whole page isn't changing just the iframe element. If i click on an element in the navbar the icon of the element is disappearing.

Comment: i can show you the navbar html code?